# SQL query where clause to return rows does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a query aganist a table to find what values are missing, see sample below. I want a query that returns matching rows along with unmatched ones..

```
select first, last, id
  from sometable
 where id not in (1234, 5678, 918, 123, 345, 567, 789, 901, 111, 222, 333, 444)

+----------+---------+---------+
| Returned | | |
+----------+---------+---------+
| FIRST    | LAST    | ID      |
| Fir      | Las     | 123     |
| Sand     | Mud     | 222     |
| Stud     | Wood    | 345     |
| Nail     | Metal   | 444     |
| Fiber    | Glass   | 567     |
| Max      | Money   | 789     |
| Less     | Piece   | 5678    |
+----------+---------+---------+



+----------+-------+------+
| Expected |       |      |
+----------+-------+------+
| FIRST    | LAST  | ID   |
| Fir      | Las   | 123  |
| Sand     | Mud   | 222  |
| Stud     | Wood  | 345  |
| Nail     | Metal | 444  |
| Fiber    | Glass | 567  |
| Max      | Money | 789  |
| Less     | Piece | 5678 |
|          |       | 1234 |
|          |       | 918  |
|          |       | 901  |
|          |       | 111  |
|          |       | 333  |
+----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Huh?  Isn't that just returning all rows in the table?  Not clear.

Comment: If you want all rows and non-matching rows, and all this data is in the same table, just do a `select * from table`

Comment: I think by ` not in` you mean `in`. So you need to get all records from the `in` clause. If matched then the values, else null. Is that it?

Comment: @OldProgrammer not every single row in a table. What ever in the where clause.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for select *

Comment: @MyShopping You're welcome.

Comment: "To find what values are missing" - missing from what? The question as you posed it makes no sense.

Comment: According to the data you've shown you should be getting no results whatsoever, because you're excluding every `ID` value shown. Clearly there's something else going on here but from the code and data shown I can't for the life of me determine what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand u corectly this might work but add the conditions u want and u dont want

```
    Select id, first,last from sometable
   Where id in ('123','222','345')
   Union
    Select null, null, last from sometable
   Where id in ('345','444')
```

Comment: That requires he know which ids are present or not beforehand.

Comment: Well the he replace the second union with not in for theid he knows @shawn

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like this

**[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad7431/8)**

```
select t.id,s.first,s.last
from 
(SELECT regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) id
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
        '1234, 5678, 918, 123, 345, 567, 789, 901, 111, 222, 333, 444' AS txt 
     -- Put your in clause above without new line.
        FROM dual
    )  
     CONNECT BY regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
) t
left join
sometable s
on t.id=s.id
```

Output

```
+------+--------+--------+
|  ID  | FIRST  |  LAST  |
+------+--------+--------+
|  123 | Fir    | Las    |
|  222 | Sand   | Mud    |
|  345 | Stud   | Wood   |
|  444 | Nail   | Metal  |
|  567 | Fiber  | Glass  |
|  789 | Max    | Money  |
| 5678 | Less   | Piece  |
|  111 | (null) | (null) |
| 1234 | (null) | (null) |
|  918 | (null) | (null) |
|  901 | (null) | (null) |
|  333 | (null) | (null) |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't able to do that since you only will receive one column data instead of the whole result set.

Check if your table columns allow null and if they do, you can add the exception values(1234, 5678, 918, 123, 345, 567, 789, 901, 111, 222, 333, 444) with a simple insert at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Put the ids you're interested in into a temp table, and do an outer join:

(Sqlite syntax; adjust as needed for Oracle)

```
CREATE TABLE sometable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first TEXT, last TEXT);
-- Populate sometable
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO temptable VALUES (1234), (5678), (918), (123), (345), (567), (789),
                             (901), (111), (222), (333), (444);
SELECT first, last, t.id AS id
 FROM temptable AS t
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
      sometable AS s
 ON s.id = t.id;
```

produces

```
first       last        id        
----------  ----------  ----------
                        111       
Fir         Las         123       
Sand        Mud         222       
                        333       
Stud        Wood        345       
Nail        Metal       444       
Fiber       Glass       567       
Max         Money       789       
                        901       
                        918       
                        1234      
Less        Piece       5678
```

Edit: You could probably use a CTE to hold the values instead of a temporary table if so desired, too.